# Solr Search Spell check and Stemming configuration without using text file

Tags: python, solr, plone-3.x

I need help to get some information on Solr-Search. Below is the problem statement:

**Problem Statement**

1. Need to implement spell check functionality (same as google did you mean).
2. Stemming of search words. e.g. dose, dossier, dosing. If some one search for dose result will be also for dossier and dosing.

**Requirement**

Need to implement both of the functionality without using any manual text file like spellcheck.txt for spell check and synonym.txt for stemming. I want it to be configured through search engine and want taht it use some general English dictionary.

**My Understanding**

1. Solr does not provide any dictionary . Spell check can be implemented by providing a text file for spell check..
2. For stemming also we need to upload txt file.

I need to mention this in schema.xml present in solr. These text files need to be maintained manually.

I need to confirm that is there any other way to configure a general dictionary with **Solr** or any other way we can achieve these requirements through **Solr** configuration changes without using text files.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the [DirectSolrSpellcheck](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) so no dictionaries are needed.
2. You don't need text files for stemming, just an [analyzer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis).

Comment: We are using solr 1.1 and spell check analyser is present in updated solr version is there any other way to handel this.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me a sample code for DirectSolrSpellcheck as I was unable to find any implementation of this.

Comment: It's part of Solr 4.0. Else might wanna check IndexBasedSpellChecker

Comment: Thanks O. Klein for the information ......this means I have to look out for something else we cant upgrade solr to 4.0.......:)

Comment: Can FileBased and Indexed based search used simultaniouslly... in Solr 1.4